# How to set color of GNUPLOT lines in C

Tags: c, gnuplot

I am writing a program for event driven simulation of elastic collision of spherical balls(in 2D). As a output of the program I am collecting the collision points into a log file(say, data.temp) and plotting them using gnuplot.

I am following the instructions discussed here in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521209/making-c-code-plot-a-graph-automatically). My output log file looks like this.

**DATA.TEMP**(All points are not shown)

```
20.000000 0.000000 
3.535534 0.000000 
3.535534 0.000000 
45.000000 33.508349 


-20.000000 -2.500000 
-3.535534 -2.500000 
-3.535534 -2.500000 
-47.500000 -38.028654 
-47.500000 -38.028654
```

The command used for gnuplot

```
char* commandForGnuplot[] = {"set title \"Path Plot\"","plot 'data.temp' with linespoints"};
```

I am able to get a plot like this
[image]

I want the paths for different balls to be colored differently. The color should be an input from the user. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out gnuplot's docs: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node62.html

There are some examples in there for defining plot styles. You will have to do some changes in your gnuplot command string -you will probably have to define a style and change your plot command into something like this (just stick your own color in there):

```
set style line 1 lt rgb "#FF00FF" lw 3 pt 6
plot 'data.temp' with linespoints ls 1
```