# Using fprintf() to send data to gnuplot in C

Tags: c, printf, gnuplot

I'm having an issue plotting on `gnuplot` with my `C program.` When I compile it, the `popen()` function successfully opens up the gnuplot program, but once it's open, it does not receive the data from the `fprintf` stream. Here is the relevant function from my program:

```
void plot_data() {
    FILE* gnuplot = popen("wgnuplot.exe -persistent", "w");
    fprintf(gnuplot, "plot '-'\n");
    for(int j=0; j<DATA_ENTRIES; j++) fprintf(gnuplot, "%f %f %f\n", data[j].x, data[j].y, data[j].z);
    fprintf(gnuplot, "e\n");
    fflush(gnuplot);
}
```

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't receive data? Some programs wait for closed stdin (so you need to call `fclose`) and won't do anything until that.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't receive it?

Comment: @myaut According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521209/making-c-code-plot-a-graph-automatically) `fflush` should be sufficient.